# Question on difference equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Let u, v, be linearly independent eigenvectors of a 2x2 matrix A, with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda, \mu$ and let $c_1, c_2$ be scalars. Define $x_k := c_1 \lambda^ku + c_2\mu^kv$, k = 0,1,2,...

- Conclude that the sequence of vectors ${x_k}$ solves the difference equation $Ax_k = x_{k+1}$, k = 0,1,...
- How might you build a solution the difference equation $Ax_k = x_{k+1}$, k = 0,1,... with a specified initial vector $x_0$?

To start, I proved that $Ax_k = x_{k+1}$. I was just introduced to difference equations in the previous lesson, so I'm not sure where to go from here. How do I go about proving that the sequence of vectors is a solution of the difference equation given, and what is the second question really asking? It's a bit abstract.

Comment: If you're asked to show that $x=7$ solves $2x=14$, you do it by showing that $2\times7=14$. If you're asked to show that $x_k=c_1\lambda^k\dots$, you do it by showing that, with that formula for $x_k$, $Ax_k=x_{k+1}$. So it looks like you have already answered the first question.

Comment: The second question is asking you to find the numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ so that the formula for $x_k$ gives $x_0$ when you plug in $k=0$.

Comment: Any reactions to my comments?

Comment: I guess not. Too bad.